# Windows phone app that detects call, SMS and alarms and sends notification to PC

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to develop an app for windows phone that will detect calls and send notification to PC through wifi. Similarly it will also send SMS that are received to PC and when an alarm goes off in phone, a notification will be sent to PC. How should I proceed about developing this app?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language were you hoping to do this in?

Comment: C#, though if there is any other language that will be useful, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API exposed to allow you to spy on incoming calls or SMS in Windows Phone (like there was with Windows Mobile). The only option would be to build this as an OEM extension, but unless you work for HTC, Samsung or Nokia, this isn't going to be an option.

Answer (score 1):

See it's not that you cannot but to some extent you can. Like you can use Obscured Event to detect call , lock screen etc. go through this msdn discussion for details

[Detect lock and calls msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0572dbcb-dacf-4cf4-a803-8d95d31d5171/detecting-incoming-phone-call)

And as far as the alarm or the reminder is concerned you can go ahead and design a reminder system within your app. Limit is 50.

[Obscured event Windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)